# Why PubNub iOS push messages is not working?

Tags: ios, .net-core, apple-push-notifications, push, pubnub

Ive developed a .Net API that register a mobile device to a channel and sends a push notification on it.

The code is like this:

Register phone:

```
            _pubNub.AddPushNotificationsOnChannels()
                .PushType(PNPushType.APNS2)
                .Channels(new string[] {
                   device.ChannelId.ToString()
                })
                .DeviceId(device.DeviceId)
                .Topic(_settings.ApplicationBundle)
                .Environment(device.Enviroment)
                .Execute(new AddDevicePushChannel());
```

When execute, the response is 200 and no error where register.
So, i will sent the notification to my app using this code:

```
            _pubNub.Publish()
            .Channel(message.ChannelId.ToString())
            .Message(new string[] {
                  message.Text
                })
            .Execute(new PushPublishMessageChannel());
```

And again, no errors and status code is 200 on response from pubnub

**But notification never get APNs**

With same sdk, I've checked that the device belongs to the channel and according the response is ok.

- Ive already sent a push from APNs console to my deviceId and works fine.
- Of course all the configurations for iOS notifications in pubnub is ok, even the *.p8

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
        Dictionary<string, object> apnsData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {
               "aps", new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                    {
                       "alert","Hello"
                    }
            }
            }
        };

        MobilePayload mobilePayload = new MobilePayload();
        mobilePayload.pn_apns = apnsData;

        _pubNub.Publish()
            .Channel(message.ChannelId.ToString())
            .Message(mobilePayload)
            .Execute(new PushPublishMessageChannel());
```

Comment: Your `publish` message payload looks like it is missing the `pn_apns` entry?  https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/c-sharp/api-reference/publish-and-subscribe#publishing-messages-for-receipt-on-fcm-and-apns-associated-devices-sample-payload

Comment: Darryn is likely correct, but I'll go one further... unless I missed something - what is the message payload that you are publishing? Please edit your question and add the full JSON message payload, please.

Comment: already edited... still not working but all responses are 200 with error = false